# How to install Perl module Tk in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, perl, tk-toolkit

When I try to run a simple Perl script containing the instruction 'use Tk' in Windows 11 I get the following message:

> Can't locate Tkx.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tkx module) (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x64-multi-thread C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib) at teste.pl line 5.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at teste.pl line 5.

So I try to install Perl Tk module in Windows 11, I get the following messages:

```
cpan> install Tk
Running install for module 'Tk'
  SREZIC/Tk-804.036.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Strawberry\cpan\build\Tk-804.036-3
  SREZIC/Tk-804.036.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  SREZIC/Tk-804.036.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error
```

I have tried make Tk, test Tk and install Tk at the teminal Perl(command line) - cpanm, without any success.

Comment: *"cpan> install Tk"* : can you also try "cpanm Tk" ?

Comment: What you posted is useless. The error is "hidden". Run `cpan` with no arguments. From within, execute `o conf build_dir_reuse 0` and `o conf commit` and `quit`. Then run `cpan Tk` again and provide the actual error message.

Comment: Tkx and Tk are different distributions.

Comment: See https://metacpan.org/pod/Tkx